# Программа работает не так, как нужно

Tags: java, циклы, исключения

Идея состоит в том, чтобы вырисовывалась лесенка по заданной высоте, но при этом должен быть соблюден ряд условий.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

//TODO: add Exceptions

public class Mario
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int nHeight, step, space, sharp, a = 1, b;
    boolean integer;

    do {
        System.out.print("Enter height of pyramid: ");
        nHeight = scanner.nextInt();
        integer = scanner.hasNextInt();
    } while ( (!integer) || (nHeight < 1) || (nHeight > 23));

    b = nHeight - 2;

    for(step = 0; step < nHeight; step++) {
        for(space = 0; space < nHeight - a; space++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        for(sharp = 0; sharp < nHeight - b; sharp++) {
            System.out.print("#");
        }
        a++;
        b--;
        System.out.println();
    }
  }

}
```

Одно из условий - что-либо вводимое должно быть целочисленным числом. Проверку решил осуществлять с помощью переменной integer в цикле do while. Однако программа работает некорректно, то есть результат выдается после нескольких попыток ввода и не важно, проходят ограничения или нет.

[image: Некорректный результат работы программы]

Но если 17 строку убрать (и условие !integer), то программа работает как надо согласно двум остальным условиям. Что в этой строке не так? Почему она не дает нужный результат? Как это пофиксить?

Comment: Добавьте в стартовое сообщение код Вашей программы в виде текста.

Comment: На данном ресурсе не принято выкладывать скриншоты кода, приведите исходный код в тексте и используйте форматирование.

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в `integer = scanner.hasNextInt();` после того как вы использовали `scanner.nextInt();`. На входе сканера уже нет никаких данных. Уберите эту проверку.